# How to test if constant is used in JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, constants

I would like to test if a function uses a constant. For example:

```
public void functionName() {
    ...
    try {
        ...
        Logger.log(CONSTANT_NAME, ..., ...);
    } catch (...) { ... }
    ...
}
```

How would I check if functionName used CONSTANT_NAME?

Comment: You can't. Also Java will resolve constants at compile time and replace them with the corresponding string value if I remember correctly. Bytecode should confirm this

Comment: It you were not using a static method `Logger.log(....)`, you could mock the `logger` and verify the call with mockito.

Comment: Unit tests are meant to test and confirm expected behaviors, not to ensure your code is clean and so on. If you're trying to ensure the same _value_ is used, you could use PowerMock to check that the log method was called with it.

Comment: @Zircon I would not recommend using Powermock. Powermock manipulates the bytecode, just like JaCoCo does. The two tool do not play nicely together.

Comment: @Turing85 This is true and in hindsight I would not recommend it either.